# Any idea which widget to use to build this layout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this prototype to follow, but the layout, but I couldn't find a widget that keeps the images in different positions in the grid...

[image]

```
 GridView.custom(
  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
    pattern: [
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
    ],
  ),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) => Tile(index: index),
  ),
);
```

Testing flutter_staggered_grid_view and couldn't get anything close to layout.

Comment: Does it have to be with `flutter_staggered_grid_view` or ok with other widget that can reduce the performance